# Performance of varbinary comparison in T-SQL

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql, comparison

One of a table columns is of VARBINARY type, need to raise a query to evaluate rows for particular bytes pattern, following approach dramatically decreases performance:

```
declare @pattern varbinary

// 19 bytes constant
set @pattern = 0x00.....

-- r.payload is of VARBINARY type as well
SELECT .... FROM ...
WHERE substring(r.payload, 0, 19) <> @pattern
```

Is there any alternative to the given approach?

Comment: Not sure there's enough been provided for us to improve on. You could change substring to `Left(r.payload,19)`

Comment: Don't think there is anything else useful to share, query itself is rather simple and fast, no tricky joins, conditions... Amount of rows in a table ~5000. And `Left()` didn't help, but thanks for idea! I like `left()` because code looks more clear and self descriptive.

Comment: Do you have an index set on the table for payload? That might help

Comment: You might be able to save the (presumably expensive) substring in most cases by doing col >= pattern AND col <= pattern + 0xFF.

Comment: @Christian Barron: Do you mean index on varbinary column or any index? There are clustered and one NC indexes on other columns.

Comment: @usr: not sure I got the idea, please elaborate

Comment: Ah yes I forgot it's varbinary so ignore that

Comment: The idea is that SUBSTRING is expensive and comparison is cheap. So before we are doing the substring check on the first 19 bytes we compare the prefix to see that it actually can match. If the 19 byte prefix matches then r.payload must be >= @pattern. Does that make sense? The goal is to reduce CPU usage and even enable index usage.

Comment: No Idea if it will do any difference, but what about if you cast instead of substring. `WHERE CAST(r.payload as varbinary(19)) <> @pattern`

Comment: @Magnus I also thought that converting it to a `VARBINARY(19)` would be faster, but I just tested and it actually isn't.

Comment: @sll I think there might be something else going on here that is affecting performance that is not specifically this VARBINARY field. I posted my test script at http://pastebin.com/0RFUL7W5 and it uses 50k rows (compared to your 5k rows) and it returns very quickly even without any of potential optimization discussed here. So prior to add a new field, maybe post the full schema to your table and maybe the full query? maybe even a few rows of sample data?

Comment: Are you sure the "dramatic decreases in performance" is because of this part of the `WHERE` clause ? Are you using any User Defined Functions perhaps ? Even when the system needs to check these 5000 records one by one, bit for bit, it would still take no measurable time on a modern CPU.

Comment: @usr I also figured that the SUBSTRING would be expensive, but it turns out to be very efficient.

Comment: @sll The code snippet in the question, are you actually declaring the `@pattern` to be just `VARBINARY` by itself, or `VARBINARY(19)`? If you are not specifying a max length then that could be _a_ problem, even if not _the_ problem, since the default length when declaring a `VARCHAR` / `NVARCHAR` / `VARBINARY` variable is just 1, as in you get a `VARBINARY(1)` variable if actually doing `DECLARE @Pattern VARBINARY;`. Also, while probably not a problem, the min starting value for a `SUBSTRING` is 1, not 0.

Comment: @sll - How wide is the `payload` column in your table? If this is `varbinary(max)` or wide enough to take the row size over 8096 bytes, it will be stored off page, meaning an additional page lookup for each row to do the comparison.

Comment: @srutzky, yes its effecient but usr is correct to do the between translation as substring is not sargable, where as the between would let him use the index.

Comment: @MichaelB If the data is small enough to fit in an index and not need a separate persisted computed column, then the difference between the SUBSTRING / CONVERT / "between" methods is rather small, even on 50k rows (10x what the OP has). So while it does appear that the "between" method is slightly faster for the smaller values, that does not explain the issue that the OP is seeing, unless 10 milliseconds is "dramatically worse". But with a VARBINARY(MAX) filled with 14k bytes, the "between" method was the same as the SUBSTRING, and both are worse than the CONVERT.

Comment: True, this only helps if the varbinary column is 900 bytes or less, but that's a pretty considerable use case. If the data exceeds it he can set up a persisted column on the first 900 bytes and then create an index on it.

Comment: @Magnus, not sure why but the `CAST` seems to alter the end of the binary !!!

Comment: @Jodrell I address the issue that I believe you are seeing in my answer. I think you are assuming that the `SUBSTRING` is correct and that the `CAST` is hence wrong. But it is really the opposite. By using `0` as the starting index of the `SUBSTRING` you are actually chopping off the final character and getting 18 bytes instead of 19. The `CAST` (or `CONVERT`) is correctly returning 19 bytes.

Comment: @srutzky, your points on `SUBSTRING` are spot on, I've amended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go, use a [calculated column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms186241.aspx) to store the first 19 bytes, `PERSISTED` so you can index it.

[A demonstration can be found here on SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0cb6b/1)

When I perform the linked test, the persisted and indexed approach is about 5 times faster. This might increase significantly if the average `[Payload]` is very large.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[YourTable]
(
    [Id] INT CONSTRAINT [PK_YourTable] PRIMARY KEY,
    [Payload] VARBINARY(MAX),
    [Prefix] AS CAST([Payload] AS BINARY(19)) PERSISTED
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_YourTable_Prefix] ON [YourTable]([Prefix]);
```

allowing,

```
SELECT
            [Id]
    FROM
            [YourTable]
    WHERE
            [Prefix] <> @pattern
```

or some such.

---

It is not entirely clear to me what your are trying to achieve but potentially the use of [`HASHBYTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415(v=sql.100).aspx) might be useful.

Comment: Have you tested this? I tested against 50,000 rows and see no significant gain for using a separate `VARBINARY(19) PERSISTED` computed field. I tried the `SUBSTRING`, a `CONVERT(VARBINARY(19),`, and a persisted computed column, The only diff for either CPU or elapsed time was only a few milliseconds. I suspect the issue is that it is an inequality test (`<>`) and not an equality test (`=`).

Comment: @srutzky Even with the index?

Comment: @Magnus Yes. I have posted my test script on PasteBin so you and others can try. Maybe I did something wrong, but I'm pretty sure that I didn't. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/0RFUL7W5

Comment: @srutzky it's an interesting testscript, but you should apply some aggregation over the resultset and store that in @DevNull or @ID. Currently you only pick up 1 value from what are likely to be MANY records due to the `<>`; I'm not sure if that would result in the same scenario as the OP had in mind.

Comment: @deroby Doing the SELECT on `@DevNull = field` is merely to remove SSMS and it receiving and drawing the result grid from the test environment. The variable will pick up each value as it is found and will end up with the last row that matched the query. So there are many records that do match (49950 rows for the 50k test), but that should be irrelevant. This is just a technique to ensure that SSMS requesting more memory for the results grid does not skew the results in favor of either test case.

Comment: I assume that to be the net effect too, but making it do a `COUNT()` or even better a `CHECKSUM_AGG(BINARYCHECKSUM())` would 'force' the query optimizer to actually read all the values and return a consistent number; thus giving the test-script the added benefit of showing each approach returns the same result.

Comment: @deroby Fair enough point about the CHECKSUM functions providing additional insight. I have updated (again ;-) the test script. I still don't see much of a difference in any of the 3 approaches. Of course, neither do I see across 50k rows (10x what the OP is having issues with) any performance issues at all.

Comment: @srutzky, Its vary hard to fix a problem until you can recreate it. After a little testing I've amended my answer slightly.

Comment: @srutzky, I have tested, see link and try yourself, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26084/1

Comment: @Jodrell I ran your test and it's unfairly skewed in favor of the 2nd query as the 1st query has to load the data into the buffer pool. If you copy and paste the two SELECTs below the current ones so that it merely repeated the two tests, you would see a less dramatic difference. When I did that change to your sqlfiddle the timing went from 236 vs 21 ms to 95 vs 14 ms. Running your test on my laptop shows an avg of 15 ms with the index and 45 for the SUBSTRING. So the index _is_ better, but not hugely. I have updated my tests to both include tables with MAX types and tests including 14k bytes.

Comment: @srutzky how does the improvement vary depending on the number or rows in the result set the size of data in `[Payload]`? I can't access PasteBin so apologies if I'm missing something.

Comment: The comparative improvement of the indexed, persisted computed column increases with the number of rows and/or size of data in the `[Payload]` field. I am not arguing that your suggestion is not _an_ improvement, just that it is mostly likely irrelevant since even without the index and computed column the query returns so quickly that we can only conclude that the real problem hasn't been identified and the VARBINARY stuff is just a red herring / wild goose chase.

Comment: @sll, is there any reason my answer is not acceptable?

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible to create an additional binary column that contains these first 19 bytes?

If so, you could either create it as a persisted computed column, or as a 'real' column, and create an `INSERT` trigger that populates it when a record is added (and an `UPDATE` trigger too if the records are updated).

You could then index the new column, and rewrite the query to compare to that column instead and you would lose the expensive substring operation.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this? I see no mention of it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: Note that I am not suggesting the new field would be `VARBINARY`. `BINARY(19)` would probably be better, assuming all the values in the original column are 19 bytes or longer.

Comment: I have just tested this on our 2008R2 server, and it has no problem with me creating a table with a `VARBINARY(100)` and creating an index on it. The only problem I could foresee is if the `VARBINARY` column is longer than the allowed index length (900 bytes IIRC).

Comment: @EdB Have you tested this? I tested against 50,000 rows and see no significant gain for using a separate `VARBINARY(19) PERSISTED` computed field. I tried the `SUBSTRING`, a `CONVERT(VARBINARY(19),`, and a persisted computed column, The only diff for either CPU or elapsed time was only a few milliseconds. I suspect the issue is that it is an inequality test (`<>`) and not an equality test (`=`).

Comment: @srutzky: one thing to notice is that when there is a persisted computed column with an index on, the query optimizer will recognize when you try use the same formula on the original field and go for the indexed field. In the PasteBin example you posted, the two last queries BOTH use the IX_BinaryStuff_Prefix !

Comment: @deroby Interesting. In that case, I would have to have a 2nd table, copied from the first, that does not have the index to see a truer comparison. I will see if I can update the script accordingly.

Comment: In fact, if you're not able or allowed to add a (computed) column to the table, you could even create a view on it that returns the same computed value and then add a clustered index to it (** some extra puzzling required). When selecting from the original table, the query optimizer will recognize the formula as the one in the indexed view and thus use said index. The optimizer really is kinda cool... until it goes haywire and makes you pull your hairs =)

Comment: @deroby I have updated the test script on PasteBin. It doesn't seem to make difference, and in some runs of the test it seems like the table with the Persisted Computed Column (i.e. the `WithPCC` table) is slower (it is, of course, a larger table due to the persisted computed column ;-)

Comment: The reason you see little difference is (IMHO) because the optimizer (thanks to the statistics) 'guesses' that there is little use in using the index over the actual table because 1) it will need to process nearly all records anyway 2) assuming we need a field outside the index, we'll have to scan BOTH the index and the table! 3) the table isn't much 'wider' than the index anyway. Once the table gets wider (read: more columns), things start to change. I've added a bit to your test script here : http://pastebin.com/0Y27QxjD (try to run it in e.g. Sql Sentry Plan Explorer)

Comment: @srutzky - Note that the OP didn't say how big the 'payload' column is. Your test script uses `VARBINARY(100)`, but it could well be larger, or even `VARBINARY(MAX)`. In this case, the column would be stored off page, and whilst the `substring()` may not be expensive, the fetching of the off-page data for the comparison certainly would be. The additional column for the initial 19 bytes should be stored on page, which would mean any comparison to this would be fast. In your example, the `VARBINARY(100)` would also be stored on page, as the row width is well under 8k.

Comment: @EdB I tested more and found that the same amount of data, but now in `VARBINARY(MAX)`, was only slightly slower than before. The index is a little more attractive, but we are still talking about 10  - 20 ms on 10x the rows that the OP has. Of course, adding 14k bytes to each row made a bigger difference and the index still performed well. Still, the SUBSTRING and "between" methods were only 100 - 130 ms slower than the index, and the CONVERT about 60 ms slower. So I don't think any of this is the true issue for the OP, but without more info (that we both asked for) there is nothing to go on.

Comment: After further testing I can confirm that you cannot index a `VARBINARY(MAX)` column but you can index a `VARBINARY(n)` column. A computed column using just `SUBSTRING` will assume the `VARBINARY(MAX)` type.

Comment: @Jodrell That's why you need to convert to VARBINARY(19) in the computed column expression...that will force the datatype of the computed column. I have that in my test code, but I guess you can't get to PasteBin :-(

Answer (score 3):

More than likely the question being asked here is misleading in terms of finding the true cause of the query to slow down. There have been some good suggestions here but far too little testing. I have done fairly thorough testing, posted here for those who want to try for themselves:

http://pastebin.com/0RFUL7W5

I tested with 50k rows as opposed to the OP's stated 5k rows. The tests include tables both with and without the indexed, persisted computed column and variations on those two tables for the `Payload` field to be `VARBINARY(100)` and `VARBINARY(MAX)`. And the `VARBINARY(MAX)` field tests first test just the difference in datatype as the initial dataset is identical to what is in the `VARBINARY(100)` tables (the data in this case is still on the data page), and then the MAX tables are updated to push the data size to 14k bytes per row (the data in this case is now moved off to lob pages.

These tests need to be run individually so that one test does not skew the results of another test. And each test should be run multiple times.

Running these tests on my laptop shows that, between the variations of VARBINARY(100), VARBINARY(MAX) with <= 100 bytes, and VARBINARY(MAX) with 14k bytes:

- the methods of SUBSTRING, CONVERT, and "< @Pattern OR > @Pattern + 0xFF" are greatly impacted by the datatype and data size, hence each has potential to be the better choice depending on the actual schema and data
- the indexed persisted computed column *is* generally better than the 3 methods mentioned above, but never by more than 110 or so milliseconds.

**What does all of this mean? It means:**

- This question cannot be answered without first getting more information from the OP, specifically the full table schema (including all indexes) AND some sample data. The problem is that the timing differences between the assumed current situation and any of the possible fixes is so small (110 milliseconds on 50k rows while the OP only has 5k rows) that it is doubtful that filtering on the `VARBINARY` is the true cause of any query slowness. Even the slowest method would return too quickly on 5000 rows to even be noticeable.
- While there have been some good suggestions for improving performance on the stated scenario, without proper testing some suggestions that look good might not show any improvement at all. Assumptions should not be made on how SQL Server will react, nor do they need to be made since any situation can be tested (though structuring the tests properly can be a bit tricky.

**Bonus lesson:**

Be *very* careful when copying and pasting code posted in a question (or even in an answer for that matter). Why not? Because you might be copying a bug. A bug such as using `0` as the starting position for a `SUBSTRING` function in SQL. This is fine for most languages, but the starting index for strings in SQL is `1`. Why does this matter? Because the number of characters below `1` that you specify for the start position is deducted from the length. Meaning, using `SUBSTRING([Payload], 0, 19)` actually performs `SUBSTRING([Payload], 1, 18)`. Likewise, using `SUBSTRING(field, -1, 19)` would actually perform `SUBSTRING([Payload], 1, 17)`.

Also, the code shown in the question also uses `DECLARE @Pattern VARBINARY` which actually creates a `VARBINARY(1)` variable instead of what I assume was the intended `VARBINARY(30)`. For `VARCHAR` / `NVARCHAR` / `VARBINARY`, the default length is 30 in some cases (such as for table columns) and 1 in other cases (such as local variables).

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following and for 500K rows in my test it works very fast!

What's important here: You need to have a really good clustered index! Clustered Index should always be: 
**NUSE**

- **N**arrow as possible, in terms of the number of bytes it stores
- **U**nique – to avoid the need for SQL Server to add a "uniqueifier" to duplicate key values
- **S**tatic – ideally, never updated
- **E**ver-increasing – to avoid fragmentation and improve write performance

I created the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[YourTable]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Payload] VARBINARY(MAX),
    Prefix AS CAST(LEFT([Payload],19) AS BINARY(19)) PERSISTED 
)

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx1 ON dbo.YourTable(Id)
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idex ON dbo.YourTable (Prefix)
GO
```

So the Prefix computed column is BINARY(19) and always the first 19 Bytes. The only operation SQL Server has to do is a Clustered Index Scan.

Comment: SPECIAL THANKS TO THIS BEAUTIFUL POST: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/effective-clustered-indexes/

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly an alternative ... more of an enhancement...

Create a columnstore index on your payload field

```
CREATE COLUMNSTORE INDEX payloadcsindex 
    ON yourdb.yourschema.yourtable ( payload )
```

You will end up with an in-memory Columnstore Index Scan that could give 10x performance improvement with your existing query.

Comment: This feature is available since 2012 but thanks for attention to my question

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do a `LIKE` on the column. But you can't because `LIKE` only works on `varchar` or `nvarchar` columns.

Let's pretend for a moment its a `nvarchar(4000)` column, and you want to look for anything that starts with this 19 byte pattern. A like that ends with a `%` gets optimized into a between query by the plan.

For instance consider this query:

```
select data FROM #a
where data like N'006%'
```

The query plan optimizer has turned it into the following condition:

```
Start: [tempdb].[dbo].[#a].data >= Scalar Operator(N'006'), End: [tempdb].[dbo].[#a].data < Scalar Operator(N'007')
```

Thus we can replace your search with:

```
select data 
from my_table
where data >= @searchPattern and data < (convert(varbinary,1)+@searchPattern)
```

If the varbinary column is indexed then this search should be very well optimized.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few observations/suggestions:

1. You are probably getting similar benchmark results for the different queries because of SQL Server optimizations. To compare the performance of the queries properly you will need to avoid those optimizations. 
   However before you do that, please make sure that you only try this in a test environment. 
   I repeat do not do this in a production environment!
2. Querying against a prefix column will definitely improve the performance of your queries.
3. Since the prefix you are querying for is a fixed length (19), you should use the BINARY(19) datatype for that column. Some of the other suggestions here will create a VARBINARY column.
4. I would personally avoid putting Triggers on tables if possible. See C# example for one possible alternative.
5. In my tests querying using Equality was faster than SUBSTRING, which in turn was faster than LEFT

How I got to that conclusion was by loading about 15000 files into a test database and executing the different types of queries (multiple times), with the following results:

1. Equality check using a prefix  column -> 191 ms
2. SUBSTRING  -> 20448 ms  = 107x slower
3. LEFT  ->  34091 ms   = 178x slower

Here is a SQL script to create the test table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files]
(
    [Id]            [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Path]          [varchar](260)      NOT NULL,
    [Prefix]        [binary](19)        NOT NULL,
    [AllBytes]      [varbinary](MAX)    NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Files] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

And now the queries (Run these in different Tabs):

1.

```
--1.    Equality check using a prefix  column -> 191 ms
--WARNING!! Do not run this on a production server
--Clear SQL optimizations
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO

DECLARE @pattern BINARY(19) --NOTE use BINARY not VARBINARY to match the column type exactly 
SET @pattern = 0x4D5A90000300000004000000FFFF0000B80000 --Start of EXE / DLL files

SELECT  [Path]
FROM    [dbo].[Files]
WHERE   Prefix <> @pattern
```

2.

```
--2.    SUBSTRING  -> 20448 ms  = 107x slower
--WARNING!! Do not run this on a production server
--Clear Cache
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO


DECLARE @pattern BINARY(19) 
SET @pattern = 0x4D5A90000300000004000000FFFF0000B80000 --Start of EXE / DLL files
SELECT  [Path]
FROM    [dbo].[Files]
WHERE   SUBSTRING(AllBytes, 0, 19) <> @pattern
```

3.

```
-- 3.   LEFT  ->  34091 ms   = 178x slower
--WARNING!! Do not run this on a production server
--Clear Cache
CHECKPOINT;
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
GO


DECLARE @pattern VARBINARY(19)
SET @pattern = 0x4D5A90000300000004000000FFFF0000B80000 --Start of EXE / DLL files
SELECT  [Path]
FROM    [dbo].[Files]
WHERE   LEFT(AllBytes, 19) <> @pattern
```

And now for some code to create the test data:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace SO
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //!! To keep this EXAMPLE as simple as possible I'm leaving off all error handling and taking other shortcuts I wouldn't normal advise.

            const string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=yourServer;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Integrated Security=True";
            const string folderToProcess = @"C:\Program Files";  //choose folder with your test files
            const int prefixLength = 19;

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(folderToProcess, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(filePath);

                    //I'm only using ReadAllBytes here to keep this example simple. 
                    //This isn't appropriate for large files because it'll load the entire file into memory
                    byte[] allBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

                    //To keep things simple I'm assuming we're only working with binary values that are >= prefix length
                    if (allBytes.Length < prefixLength) { continue; }

                    //This can also be accomplished using SQL 
                    byte[] prefix = new byte[prefixLength];
                    Array.Copy(allBytes, prefix, prefixLength);

                    //Rather use a stored procedure here
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Files (Path, Prefix, AllBytes) Values(@path, @prefix, @allBytes)", connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add("@path", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 260).Value = filePath;
                        command.Parameters.Add("@prefix", SqlDbType.Binary, prefixLength).Value = prefix;             //DataType is Binary!!
                        command.Parameters.Add("@allBytes", SqlDbType.VarBinary, allBytes.Length).Value = allBytes;   //DataType is VarBinary
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                connection.Close();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("All Done !");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also an option if the computed column isn't an option.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    val VARBINARY(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @t SELECT 0x00000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 0x00001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 0x00010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 0x00100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
INSERT INTO @t SELECT 0x00000f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

declare @pattern varbinary(19)
declare @pattern2 varbinary(19)
set @pattern = 0x0001
set @pattern2 = @pattern+0xFF

select @pattern,@pattern2

SELECT
    *
FROM @t
WHERE val<@pattern
OR val>@pattern2
```

Answer (score 0):

More input please, otherwise this is a textbook question.

Please provide us with some sample data and 
let us know your application.  Sometimes there are application behaviours which have broader solutions.

I noticed you categorized this as SQL Server 2008, so you should:

turn page compression on, 
disable automatic statistic generation, 
look at you sys.dm_os_wait_stats, and 
check for high fragmentation.

What sort of records are you reading that require the <> comparison?
Is it anything being assigned to a second memory stream to process?
Can you make any changes to prevent data to be written to disk?

How long is it taking to process this table?